# Node.js Express using require vs app.get

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript

```
# app.get "/example", example.index

# require("./routes/index") app
```

I know my first line goes to my controller called example and uses the index function.
I'm not really sure what the second line does. Is one better than the other? A full explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first line: `app.get "/example", example.index` says that if someone hits the URL `http://localhost:3000/example`, then you are loading the `example` file (presumably `require`d somewhere above) and running the `index` function on it.

The second line `require("./routes/index") app` is simply `require`ing some file called `index.coffee` in the `routes` folder and passing `app` as a variable.

Comment: `localhost:3000` is pretty much the default host:port for a node app. The `/example` is because you are specifying the `app.get '/example'`